# Exit Cmd window after execution of script in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell, cmd

I would like to Exit the CMD window after execution of script (currently I am exiting CMD manually by writing exit in the CMD window, after which VBA continues running)

```vb
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errorCode As Long
errorCode = wsh.Run(sCmdline, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

'-- Finally Run function Arguments ----- 
 errorCode = wsh.Run("cmd /k systeminfo >D:\Tools\MyScript\SystemInfo.txt", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errorCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
    Set wsh = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errorCode & "."
    Set wsh = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Once again: **please include this in your question by clicking the [edit] button!** Anyway, try replacing `cmd /k` by `cmd /c`...

Comment: @ aschipfl Thank you !!!! Its working. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to close the cmd after you open it. `/C` flag is the best here, because it carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

So, you should write:

```
errorCode = wsh.Run("cmd /c systeminfo >D:\Tools\MyScript\SystemInfo.txt", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

which will work.

Answer (score 1):

In your `sCmdLine` (which is not defined in your question), just add `&& exit` at the end to execute the commands one after the other in a single line.

If your original command was `sCmdLine = "cmd.exe /S /K ping www.google.com"`, then it would become `sCmdLine = "cmd.exe /S /K ping www.google.com && exit"`.